# How to integrate hockey App with Hybrid mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hockeyapp

I am trying to  integrate my **Hybrid Mobile App** (Inonic + Cordova) with [hockey App](http://hockeyapp.net) 
but the problem is Hockey App is support Native apps (According to my info). So is there any guide available for that?
*Hybrid App integration with Hockey app*.

When I try to follow hockey app integration with **android platform** (hybrid app) it also said me to add some code in **main activity** so where i can find this

Answer (score 2):

Main activity is inside Android platform... cordova/platforms/android/src/...

Put in onCreate method the Register...

There also some plugins for help in this task like https://github.com/peutetre/cordova-plugin-hockeyapp

Take into account that a lot of crash JavaScript problems do not crash in native world it would be helpful to use additional way to communicate controlled errors for example the saveException method, try to expose this by plugin into javascript, it will let store context information error: http://hockeyapp.net/help/sdk/android/3.0.1/net/hockeyapp/android/ExceptionHandler.html

I have tested the solution **for Android only** in a fork of the previous mentioned plugin:
https://github.com/m-alcu/cordova-plugin-hockeyapp

There are several actions available but yo only need to use "start" and "saveException" for controlled errors to be send to hockeyapps.

hockeyapp.js:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

var hockeyapp = {
    start:function(success, failure, token) {
        exec(success, failure, "HockeyApp", "start", [ token ]);
    },
    feedback:function(success, failure) {
        exec(success, failure, "HockeyApp", "feedback", []);
    },
    saveException:function(success, failure, description) {
        exec(success, failure, "HockeyApp", "saveException", [ description ]);
    }    
};

module.exports = hockeyapp;
```

hockeyapp.java:

```
package com.zengularity.cordova.hockeyapp;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static net.hockeyapp.android.ExceptionHandler.saveException;
import net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackManager;
import net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager;
import net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManagerListener;

public class HockeyApp extends CordovaPlugin {

    public static boolean initialized = false;
    public static String token;
    public static String description;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (action.equals("start")) {
            token = args.optString(0);
            CrashManager.register(cordova.getActivity(), token, null);
            initialized = true;
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        } else if(action.equals("feedback")) {
            token = args.optString(0);
            FeedbackManager.register(cordova.getActivity(), token, null);
            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    FeedbackManager.showFeedbackActivity(cordova.getActivity());
                }
            });
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;

        } else if(action.equals("saveException")) {
            description = args.optString(0);
            if(initialized) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(cordova.getActivity(), "problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Exception e = new Exception("Send problem");
                        saveException(e, new CrashManagerListener() {
                            public String getDescription() {
                                return description;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                callbackContext.success();
                return true;
            } else {
                callbackContext.error("cordova hockeyapp plugin not initialized, call start() first");
                return false;                
            }  
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

example of use this plugin in a hellowold example (index.js):

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        hockeyapp.start(
            function() { alert('hockeyapp initialised'); },
            function(msg) { alert(msg); },
            '< your APP ID >');

        hockeyapp.saveException(
            function() { alert('hockeyapp saveException'); },
            function(msg) { alert(msg); },
            'Something wrong has happened: bla bla bla...');    
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Hockey stores these controlled exceptions in the file directory of the app and asks to send it the next time user opens app:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you mean to use plugin instead following the direction of hockeyApp. so how many times i use this plugin methods

Comment: The plugin does the same as Hockeyapp tutorials. It implements the regiter ("start") and the feedback activity ("feedback"). My comment is that probably you will need sometimes additional info about Javascript crashes that are not detected by the crash native handler... probably this plugin can be modified to expose the ExceptionHandler.saveException() in those cases...

Comment: + help full for me but still some confusion

Comment: using the plugin crash handling is much difficult. can you share any detail guide

Comment: hockeyapp.start line throwing 'Uncaught ReferenceError: hockeyapp is not defined ' exception