# Howto integrate HockeyApp in Ionic as a Module

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, hockeyapp

i'm trying to integrate hockeyapp as a module like in this topic :
[How to integrate hockey App with Hybrid mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632658/how-to-integrate-hockey-app-with-hybrid-mobile-app)

But i'm unable to make it work. I've added the cordova plugin https://github.com/peutetre/cordova-plugin-hockeyapp. it seem successfully integrated (when i'm building the app, the source are present), but i'm unable to use it.

I'm a beginner with ionic, i've tried different thing, but none worked.

the last i've tried it to make a module like this :

```
    angular.module('ngHockeyApp', [])

.factory('hockeyapp', function ($q, $window) {

    function start(success, failure, appid) {
        console.log('start');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        cordova.exec(success, failure, "HockeyApp", "start", [ appid ]);
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    ...

    return {
        start: start,
        feedback: feedback,
        forceCrash: forceCrash,
        checkForUpdate: checkForUpdate
    };

});
```

in this case, the problem is that it cannot resolve cordova, so it cant make call to native code.

Anyone having integrated HockeyApp in ionic can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

HockeyApp does not have an official integration with Ionic, but the answer in this thread might help:
[How to integrate hockey App with Hybrid mobile app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632658/how-to-integrate-hockey-app-with-hybrid-mobile-app)

Comment: This is what the OP is trying (his first phrase).